# Как сделать панель (тулбар), как у вас?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как сделать панель вверху сайта, которую можно закрыть и которая сохраняется в куках и больше не показывается после закрытия?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: И как вообще делать обычные панели вверху сайта и с крестиком для закрытия?

Comment: Обычный div, который показывается при выполнении каких-то условий. закрывается обычным `$("#my-info-div").hide();` или `$("#my-info-div").remove();`. В чем сложность-то?